# How to change WYSIWYG default editor of administrator laravel package

Tags: php, laravel, administrator

I am using administrator package of laravel in a project.

[Link](http://administrator.frozennode.com/)

The WYSIWYG field editor if administrator is ckeditor. But i want to change with [redactor](http://redactorjs.com)
.

can any one help me how to i change this editor.

Please Please help me.